# Replace All Occurrences After a Character using Oracle regexp_replace

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to replace ALL **',** with **'||** .However, I only replace ', that show up after the very first word **begin** (case insensitive). We might have multiple BEGIN, but once I meet the word begin for the first time, I want to replace all occurrences AFTER begin.

Here is my code that replaces ALL without exception:

```
regexp_replace(column_name, ''',', '''||', 1, 0, 'i');
```

Thanks

Comment: Dear Qanat Tajrediat, you should considering update your work according to the editted answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply find the position of the first word **begin** in your column and add to `position` parameter of [`regexp_replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)

So you should use this

```
regexp_replace(column_name, ''',', '''||', regexp_instr(column_name, '\sbegin\s', 1, 1, 0, 'i'), 0, 'i');
```

Editted: According to suggestion from `Gary_W`, you should consider using keyword **'\sbegin\s'** (updated in above code) to avoid finding **wrong word** when `begin` is part of another word like `function get_beginning_status`.

P/S: Using `\s` instead of `non-breaking-space` in case string text in `column_name` have `line break`

Comment: You might want to add a space either side of BEGIN in case the string 'BEGIN' is part of another word.